# Bootstrap search bar in nav-tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to create a blog for my parents. For the navbar I am using the Bootstrap navs nav-tabs like so:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  ...
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  ...
</ul>
```

I want to add a search bar such as you can include within navbars but I am not able to find any evidence of others trying to do so, so is it possible to add a search input to a nav-pills justified class?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_form_addon&stacked=h) provides some example.

You can try this code

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><input Type="text" placeholder="serach"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That uses navbar though instead of nav and nav-tabs as the classes. I can get it to work with navbar but I cannot get it to work with just a nav class

Comment: @KasunjithBimal don't post code in comments next time, you can [edit] your answer

Answer (score 0):

In the end I switch over to using `navbar` instead of `nav-tabs` and added the links as before. Then I added the search bar using the native `form` template as part of `navbar`